# Web3.py - Unable to import 'web3' even though web3 is installed

Tags: python, web3py

I've installed web3 today via `pip install web3` and since then I've been trying to `import web3` into the current working file without any success.

No matter what I do, I get "Unable to import 'web3'.

Pip list finds web3 (web3 5.19.0).

Code in the file:

```
import web3

from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, TestRPCProvider

infura_url = 'URL'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

isConnected = web3.isConnected()
blocknumber = web3.eth.blockNumber
```

**Update**

I know what's wrong, pip installs packages in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages` meanwhile python is looking for the packages in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What python version are you using?  How are you running your script?  The possible reason for your error is that you're using a version of python that's not the same as the one that's with pip.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.4.  I'm not even running the script, I just pasted the above from a tutorial on the internet into a name.py file into VSC, and immediately shows an error under "import" and "from".

Comment: What version is ```pip```?

Comment: Pip version 21.1.1 as per pip --version

Comment: Do you have another version of python installed on your system?

Comment: As per py -0 (hopefully it's the right one), only version 3.9

Comment: Hello did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need the first import and it is effecting you'r code cause you'r variable called web3, just delete

> import web3

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

pip list is showing web3 library, after figuring out I found that it is a problem of vs code python editor. Run the following code irrespective of editor error message
if run successfully

```
from web3 import Web3
print(Web3)
```

It will give output

```
<class 'web3.main.Web3'>
```

Then it mean it has some vs code python editor problem but you can ignore warning and use web3 for coding purpose

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need the first import and it is effecting you're code cause you're variable called web3, just delete

```
import web3
```

and for webSocket use it:

```
Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(infura_url))
```

and for http use it:

```
Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Visual Studio Code.
I tried to open the code with PyCharm and it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

you must install visual c ++ build tools // desktop development with c ++ // then you install web3 in the console and it will not give you an error

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your local version. I would try quitting the app and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some suggested that it works despite of the error. But in my case it wasn't.  So, the solution for me was installing web3 globally on my local system, outside of the virtual env using `pip3 install web3` command. I'm using python3 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

delete first line of code.
also delete import HTTPProvider or use code below

`web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(infura_url))`

instead of

`web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))`

Answer (score 0):

you should set up a virtual environment to avoid the type of issue you just described (packages being installed in different locations on your machine)

check this out for more info:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

heres my quick guide

open up a terminal, navigate to the root directory of your project and set up a virtual environment

`python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

to activate your virtual environment run the following command

`source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate`

now run `pip install web3`

now that your virtual environment is activated and you've installed python3 you should be able to run your file

`python name_of_file.py`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.
The solution is to rename the python file from Web3.py to something else.